# GPS trajectory as equation

Tags: gps

Just wondering, is it possible to club a set of trajectory points of a trip into an equation or some king of curve function. Basically I have set of gps data points for multiple trips. I want to aggregate the data at trip level but want to express the entire trajectory as a line or equation or function. Can this be implemented?

TIA!

Regards,
Lesnar

Comment: I doubt that this makes sense, why do you want to do that, and what benefit you expect?